# Exception in tkinter callback type error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm unable to print resulting answer to a label
I was getting error add() missing positional argument self

[image: tracback]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Entry
def add(self):
    x1=float(Entry.get(e))
    y1=float(Entry.get(e1))
    ans=x1+y1
    labr.config(text="Result is %d"%ans)
def sub():
    x1=float(Entry.get(e))
    y1=float(Entry.get(e1))
    ans=x1-y1
    print("answer is ",ans)
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.title("sample calculator")
window.geometry("300x300")
lab=tkinter.Label(window,text="calculator")
e=tkinter.Entry(window)
e1=tkinter.Entry(window)
b=tkinter.Button(window,bg="green",text="add",command=add)
b1=tkinter.Button(window,bg="blue",text="subtract",command=sub)
labr=tkinter.Label(window)
lab.pack()
e.pack()
e1.pack()
b.pack()
b1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message instead of adding a picture of it (good practice on this website). You define the function add with one argument. It seems that later you call it without specifying any argument. This is what this error means.

Answer (score 1):

Your function`add` takes one argument `self` but the button `b` calls `add()` when you click on it, hence the error about a missing argument.

I think that you copied this function from a class, but you forgot to remove the `self` from the arguments because you don't use it inside `add`.